# oil furnace sooting extensively

Tags: oil

In December 2023 I noticed lottsa smoke coming from my furnace. I live in florida, so dont use it too much. I did a smoke test and draft check january 2023 and all was good.

It was still heating house fine.

Many years ago I started doing my own maintenance/tune ups because I could not find anyone in florida to do it right. Even the guy who installed it didnt set it up properly. So, I check smoke and draft at least once a year. I change filter at every take fill. Strainer, nozzle and electrodes (yes I adj them too) every year or two. There are a few other parts that Ive changed as called for in the maintenance manual, that I cant remember right now. I also got the proper specs from the manufactures. One service guy actually came with a later revised spec for a later model and some specs were different. I confirmed with the manufacturer that those specs were wrong for my model year. He also didnt check draft. I can post that letter.

Anyway Im having doubts about my tuning ability, so I again looked for someone qualified. I contacted over 70 HVAC service companies in my and neighboring counties in the past two weeks. I found no one. Many said they could, but when asked how they adj co or stack temp, then didnt know.

Last week I scrubbed out then chamber, heat exchangers, sight tubes, flue, and chimney. Whatta mess! Then I changed the nozzle which was less then 2 years old (it was dripping oil and Ive never seen that before) and even though it looked fine, I changed the pump strainer too.

Im going to order a pressure gauge to hook up permanently to the pump, to check and monitor the pressure which Ive never checked. Suggestions for a good accurate brand?

Any ideas why it was smoking so much?

tks,
paul

Comment: Smoking should be a sign of rich burning, too much oil for the amount of air.  Soot should have the same reason.  Either your nozzle is too large or your oil pump/injection pump is set too high and not stopping oil flow.

Comment: If the nozzle is dripping, an oil pool in the burner is not good either.

Answer (score 1):

A comment above mentions too-high oil pressure as a possible cause, but too-low pressure can cause a smokey flame as well. If the gear pump is severely worn, it will fail to develop enough pressure to properly atomize the fuel oil info fine droplets that burn easily and completely. You may get droplets too large, or worse, a stream  instead of a fine fog of fuel oil.

In addition, a severely worn gear pump when not running will allow fuel oil to pass through to the nozzle if the nozzle is lower than the fuel level in the tank. You said the nozzle was dripping, so this could be the cause.

I think a permanent pressure gauge on the high pressure fuel line is a great idea, and should help you solve the smoke problem.

Comment: As soon as i choose a pressure gauge ill ck pressure and shut off.

Comment: Because of clearance issues ill need a 4' tube between the pressure  guage and pump. How do i get the air out of that?

Comment: @PaulMars Air in the line won't change the pressure reading, but it could cause the flame to sputter on startup and shutdown due to the air in tubing being being a pressure reservoir. To remove air, install the gauge, start up the burner, then very slightly loosen the connection at the gauge. Air will be expelled. As soon as fuel oil starts leaking from the connection, tighten it. Protect your eyes. Best to cover the connection with a cloth to catch any spray and look for a wet spot. Remember, *slightly* loosen the connection so you don't make a mess.

Comment: Thanks 8 more to go...it says. Maybe now it will let me post

Comment: Juck checked pressure and shut off.

Running pressure was proper at 100 lbs 

Pump papers say "after shutdown it should be 80% or higher. NOTE: A and B model pumps could theoretically have a cut-off

pressure of less than 80%. The important operation is that it drops to some value and stops."

​im type A pump (a2va-7116)

​how long should it stop?

​Mine dropped immediately to 63, then after 5 minutes on a timer it was 43, then after another 5 minutes it was at 40. Then i removed gauge.

Comment: @PaulMars So your oil delay valve is leaking. It's supposed to delay fuel flow until stable airflow is established (2-5 sec?), then open suddenly at full pressure. When call for heat ends it should snap shut immediately to cut off flame before blower spins down. If this electric valve malfunctions, you get smokey starts and stops and dribble from the nozzle between runs. It should hold pressure indefinitely. I'd replace it. P.S. - No reason not to have pressure gauge permanently attached unless it's a hazard due to location.

Comment: I wish the pump manufacturer would reply to my emails. I never heard if oil delay valve or read of it in pump or burner papers.

Comment: Here #26?     https://postimg.cc/KRs3xbN5

Comment: @PaulMars Yes, that looks like the correct part. It should have one electric connector with 2 conductors plus two fittings for fuel oil, probably flare fittings, one for fuel in, the other for fuel out. When energized, it should click (open) after a short delay of 2-5 seconds. When power is cut, it should click (close) immediately. When not energized, it should hold pressure and not leak. You can bench test it if you wish. 100 psi air will work the same as 100 psi fuel oil. If it opens without a delay, fails to close immediately or leaks any air when closed, it is bad.

Comment: It's labeled as a part of the burner, not pump. But my oil input goes into pump and the output goes directly from pump to nozzle. I obviously don't understand something.  P

Comment: @PaulMars Some (smaller) burners are not equipped with delay valves from the factory but can be retrofitted. You would need a kit containing the valve, connecting tubing and wiring harness specific to your burner model. I think you would benefit from this, not least of all to stop the dribbling. But consider other possible causes of dirty combustion such as water in fuel. With low annual fuel usage and Florida humidity, it's a possibility. See "Gasoila Water Finding Paste." Smear the yellow paste onto a stick, dip to bottom of tank, turns red if there's water down there.

Comment: Yes i have the paste and check yearly. Ive never had any water, but i didnt check after last fill up. Me bad  ill do that. Well that diagram shows shut off valve as original equipment,but i think that is a later year, but same model. Suntec pump manu says if pressure goes to zero replace the pump.

Comment: I just checked with paste. No water in tank. Beckett has a different pump available for this. Yea it 109$, but might b better then adding a shutoff  valve to fix the old pump with its failing internal shutoff. But i think ill need to buy the becket external valve too. Kinda depends how easy beckett makes this for me (lets see if they respond to my emails with some real help)

Comment: @PaulMars Hope it helps, good luck.

Comment: starting a new thread titled "when to replace oil furnace shutoff solenoid

Comment: Beckett is not being helpful. Im not sure if i need new pump, that #26 solenoid or both. Please see my new thread.